# Could not resolve variable (may be a dynamic member)

Tags: actionscript-3, fdt

I created variable with datatype object and created property for this object and asignt value to it.

```
var tileModel : Object = new Object();
tileModel.property = 10;
```

But I got warning in FDT Ide. Could not resolve variable (may be a dynamic member)

I have found that possibly solution might be use /*FDT_IGNORE*/ but I would rather solve it some clasic way.

Thank you for every answer

Comment: I guess you will need an array notation instead of a dot e.g. tileModel["property"] = 10;

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use array notation as follows:

```
tileModel["property"] = 10;
```

Answer (score 2):

To not have FDT flag this as an error, you'll need to adjust the parser to ignore it.

See screenshot:[image]

Comment: Much better to modify parser rules than to change code. Thanks.